# Show that $\mathbb{E}\left[c_{\tau\wedge n}X_{\tau\wedge n}-\sum_{i=1}^{\tau\wedge n}c_i\mathbb{E}(X_i-X_{i-1}\mid\mathcal{F}_{i-1})\right]\le 0$

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

I am trying to go through a past exam paper but I don't know how to deal with stopping times since we only did 2 exercises in class... I got stuck, so I would really appreciate if someone could help me. And if the final result is correct, why would that be less than or equal to 0? Thanks a lot in advance!

**QUESTION:** Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\{\mathcal{F}\}_{n\ge 0},\mathbb{P})$ be a filtered probability space ($n\in\mathbb{N}$). Let $X:=\{X_{n}\}_{n\ge 0}$ be a non-negative submartingale with respect to $\{\mathcal{F}\}_{n\ge 0}$ such that $X_0=0$. Moreover, let $c:=\{c_n\}_{n \ge 0}$ be a non-increasing sequence of positive numbers, $\tau :=\min\{n\ge 0:c_nX_n\ge x\}$ be a stopping time and $x>0$.

Show that the following inequality holds:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[c_{\tau\wedge n}X_{\tau\wedge n}-\sum_{i=1}^{\tau\wedge n}c_i\mathbb{E}(X_i-X_{i-1} \mid \mathcal{F}_{i-1})\right]\le 0$$
**ATTEMPT:**

Since $\tau\wedge n$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable, so is $X_{\tau\wedge n}$, which is also a submartingale with respect to $\mathcal{F}_n$ and $\mathcal{F}_{\tau\wedge n}$.

Now,
$$\mathbb{E}\left[c_{\tau\wedge n}X_{\tau\wedge n}-\sum_{i=1}^{\tau\wedge n}c_i\mathbb{E}(X_i-X_{i-1}\mid\mathcal{F}_{i-1})\right]=c_{\tau\wedge n}X_{\tau\wedge n}-\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{\tau\wedge n}c_i\mathbb{E}(X_i-X_{i-1}\mid\mathcal{F}_{i-1})\right]=c_{\tau\wedge n}X_{\tau\wedge n}+\sum_{i=1}^{\tau\wedge n}\mathbb{E}\left[c_iX_{i-1}\right]-\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{\tau\wedge n}c_i\mathbb{E}(X_i\mid\mathcal{F}_{i-1})\right]\le c_{\tau\wedge n}X_{\tau\wedge n}+\sum_{i=1}^{\tau\wedge n}c_iX_{i-1}-\sum_{i=1}^{\tau\wedge n}c_iX_{i-1}=c_{\tau\wedge n}X_{\tau\wedge n}$$

Comment: I think the first line of your attempt has a typo/mistake:  How did you remove the expectation on the first term?  I would agree it can be removed if the left-hand-side was an expectation conditioned on $\mathcal{F}_n$.

Comment: I think you will also need to use the fact that $X_n$ is nonnegative for all $n$, and that $\{c_n\}$ are non-increasing.

Answer (score 2):

Note, for this all you need is that $\tau$ is a stopping time, $c_n$ are non increasing, $X_n \geq 0$ and in $L^1$.
$$
c_nX_n = \sum^n_{i=1} [c_i X_i - c_{i-1}X_{i-1}] \leq  \sum^n_{i=1} c_i (X_i-X_{i-1}) = \sum^\infty_{i=1} 1_{i \leq n}\ c_i(X_i - X_{i-1})  .
$$
Now substitute $\tau \wedge n$ for $n$.
$$
c_{\tau \wedge n}X_{\tau \wedge n} \leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty 1_{i \leq \tau\wedge n} c_i(X_i - X_{i-1})
$$
and take expecations
$$
Ec_{\tau \wedge n}X_{\tau \wedge n} \leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty E 1_{i \leq \tau\wedge n} c_i(X_i - X_{i-1}).
$$
For each $i$, use repeated conditioning on $\mathcal{F_{i-1}}$ and the fact that $\{ i \leq \tau \wedge n \} = \{\tau \wedge n \leq i -1\}^c$.
$$
Ec_{\tau \wedge n}X_{\tau \wedge n} \leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty E 1_{i \leq \tau\wedge n} c_iE[X_i - X_{i-1}\mid \mathcal{F}_{i-1}]
=E\sum_{i=1}^\infty  1_{i \leq \tau\wedge n} c_iE[X_i - X_{i-1}\mid \mathcal{F}_{i-1}]
$$
$$
=\sum_{i=1}^{\tau \wedge n}  c_iE[X_i - X_{i-1}\mid \mathcal{F}_{i-1}]
$$